# .net error: Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers

Tags: vb.net, interface

I'm getting this error when trying to implement an interface in vb.net:

```
Public Interface IFoo
   ReadOnly Property Foo() As String
End Interface

Public Class myFoo
  Implements IFoo

  Public ReadOnly Property Foo() As String
     Get
       return "Foo"
     End Get
  End Property
...
End Class
```

What is missing?

Comment: Just to inform C# can do some other stuffs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341184/why-cant-interface-readonly-properties-be-overriden-in-vb-net-when-it-is-valid

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will want to tell the code that the `myFoo.Foo` implements the `IFoo.Foo` (notice the added `Implements IFoo.Foo`):

```
Public Interface IFoo
    ReadOnly Property Foo() As String
End Interface

Public Class myFoo
    Implements IFoo

    Public ReadOnly Property Foo() As String Implements IFoo.Foo
        Get
            Return "Foo"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

As far as I know, VB.NET does not support implicit interface implementations in the same way as C# does.

Comment: I was going nuts on this one until stumbled upon your answer. Thanks!

Comment: So if the property in class and interface match. it doesn't automatically match them up then?

Comment: @Steve: no, as far as I know VB will not do that for you; you need to explicitly state that the type member implements an interface member.

Comment: Echoing @Michael 's sentiment on this one, but somewhat reluctant to like this syntactic-style! Irrespective - Very helpful answer to me, +1

Comment: Wow, VB certainly makes you be [overly] expressive in your code. This is probably a good thing.

Comment: VB sucks. Here's another reason! I can't edit generated code to add the `implements` keyword. In C# I'd use a partial class to indicate the interface, but that won't work in this case. Annoying!